# Unexpected output in my function

Tags: java

```
public class Backhand {
    int state = 0;

    Backhand(int s) {
        state = s;
    }

    public static void main(String... hi) {
        Backhand b1 = new Backhand(1);
        Backhand b2 = new Backhand(2);
        System.out.println( b2.go(b2));
    }

    int go(Backhand b) {
        if(this.state ==2) {
            b.state = 5;
            go(this);
        }
        return ++this.state;
    }
}
```

When this is run, it outputs 7. I thought  `++this.state;` should execute just once in method go and the output should be 6. Can someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get 7 is because, you call `go(this)` inside itself the `go` method, so in the end, `state` is incremented twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change `++this.state` to `this.state++` and it works fine.